# How to navigate back to previous view after sending sms is done in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am new to iphone development, i have created sms application using "Text Links(sms:) and i have created the action sheets and the buttons for email, sms. On clicking sms it navigates to the another view(UIView controller) and i wrote a code for SMS.And i faced some problem ,its not removed the view properly, it doesnt goes to the previous webview properly,(Action sheets loaded in webview)

Here my code and explanation,

I have created the custom send button programmatically for sending the sms.

I am getting  phone numbers in a textfield and  stores it to one string(phone) and i display the article title on the label, it worked dynamically.

now i want to share the article title through sms. and i have one problem, (ie)if i click send button it should go to the previous view(webview) but it display another view.. so i want to  go to the previous page properly ,when i clicked the send button.

And i also want to display the address book(Eg,default address book in the device) in my sms view page.Please guide me.

```
-(void) sendbtnclk

{
    self.String = txtfield.text;
    NSString *phone = String;
    NSString *arttitle = articleTitle; 
    NSString *sms = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sms:%@ %@",phone,arttitle];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sms]]; 

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];        
}
```

thanks,

please help me out.

Comment: please any one edit it to display the image.....

Comment: The image link you provided was pointing at your local system.  You need to host the image somewhere where we can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you use the `openURL:` method, the Text app is launched on the phone and thus the current app is dismissed. 
[Here is the relevant documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1)